# Oracle SQL Joining tables using IN clause takes long time

Tags: oracle, join, oracle11g

I have two queries which I need to join for business purpose to make them one-step process

```
SELECT
  empid,
  assest_x_id,
  asset_y_id
FROM emp e
WHERE e.empid = 'SOME_UNIQUE_VAL';
```

**result:**

```
EMPID    ASSEST_X_ID   ASSET_Y_ID
=======  ============  =========== 
1234         abc           pqr
```

*-- Even though millions rows in table this will return 1 row always within milliseconds as it's using PK column with unique value.*

Now there is another table for asset_values in separate DB current market price
(also a million rows)

```
SELECT
  asset_id,
  assest_type,
  asset_current_price
FROM asset_values@x_db a
WHERE (asset_id, assest_type) IN (('abc', 'X'), ('pqr', 'Y'));
```

**result:**

```
asset_id    asset_type assest_current_price
========    =========  =============
abc         X          10000    
pqr         Y          5000
```

*This will also return 2-3 rows always in few millisecs as Primary key is defined for combination of asset_id,asset_type values and there exists only 3 type of assets as X/Y/Z.
(Note: Not possible to normalize this table further data in business rules)*

**Now to make a one step process query in script I tried to join these queries which can take empid from user and get all desired reults.

### But now problem is that when I try to merge these two in single query like below runs for 15+ mins to give results**

```
SELECT
  a.asset_id,
  a.asset_type,
  asset_current_price
FROM asset_values@x_db a, emp b
WHERE b.empid = 'SAME_UNIQUE_VAL'
      AND (asset_id, asset_type) IN ((b.asset_x_id, 'X'), (b.asset_y_id, 'Y'));
```

Surprisingly Explain Plan is also good. (bytes:597 cost:2)
Can someone please give your expert advice on this?

```
SELECT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWSCost: 6  Bytes: 690  Cardinality: 2                   
    13 CONCATENATION                
        6 NESTED LOOPS  Cost: 3  Bytes: 345  Cardinality: 1             
            3 PARTITION RANGE SINGLE  Cost: 1  Bytes: 2,232  Cardinality: 9  Partition #: 3  Partitions accessed #1     
                2 TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID TABLE MYPRDAOWN.EMP Object Instance: 2  Cost: 1  Bytes: 2,232  Cardinality: 9  Partition #: 4  Partitions accessed #1   
                    1 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX MYPRDAOWN.EMP_7IX Cost: 1  Cardinality: 9  Partition #: 5  Partitions accessed #1
            5 FILTER  Cost: 1  Bytes: 97  Cardinality: 1        
                4 REMOTE REMOTE SERIAL_FROM_REMOTE ASSEST_VALUES XDB    
        12 NESTED LOOPS  Cost: 3  Bytes: 345  Cardinality: 1            
            9 PARTITION RANGE SINGLE  Cost: 1  Bytes: 2,232  Cardinality: 9  Partition #: 9  Partitions accessed #1     
                8 TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID TABLE MYPRDAOWN.EMP Object Instance: 2  Cost: 1  Bytes: 2,232  Cardinality: 9  Partition #: 10  Partitions accessed #1  
                    7 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX MYPRDAOWN.EMP_7IX Cost: 1  Cardinality: 9  Partition #: 11  Partitions accessed #1
            11 FILTER  Cost: 1  Bytes: 97  Cardinality: 1       
                10 REMOTE REMOTE SERIAL_FROM_REMOTE ASSEST_VALUES XDB
```

Comment: Could you please share the full explain plan? This would help. Also, adding table alias to (ASSET_ID, ASSET_TYPE) would help for query clarity. Lastly I think the IN statement could be rewritten in another way with (ASSET_ID = B.ASSET_X_ID AND ASSET_TYPE = 'X') OR (ASSET_ID = B.ASSET_X_ID AND ASSET_TYPE = 'Y')

Comment: Explain plan added (actual table_name replaced to make it generic)

Comment: I tried using OR to replace IN clause already but explain plan and results were same. :(

Comment: Are there any indexes on the assets_value table? I would assume there should be one at least on asset_id or on asset_id, type. Also, what is EMP_7IX index on? Seems strange that there is an INDEX RANGE SCAN on empid if I would assume empid to be unique in the EMP table.

Comment: I recall a similar issue when using db links. I think the issue was that the query has to run on one side or the other. You may be sending an entire table to the remote server (consuming all the time in i/o) just to perform the quick calculation over there.  I think the solution was to use a hint for the driving server (the one with the smaller table) or run the subquery to get the quick result and join that. But that was a decade ago, so I don't really recall the details.

Comment: Thank Glenn, but if you refering to /*+DRIVING_SITE(a)*/  hint, its not helping here too :(

Comment: please run it with: 'set autotrace on'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/optimops.htm#i49732:

> Nested loop joins are useful when small subsets of data are being joined and if the join condition is an efficient way of accessing the second table.

Use hash joins which:

> ... are used for joining large data sets. The optimizer uses the smaller of two tables or data sources to build a hash table on the join key in memory. It then scans the larger table, probing the hash table to find the joined rows.

to implement it use hint

```
SELECT /*+ use_hash(a,b) */ a.asset_id,
  a.asset_type,
  asset_current_price
FROM asset_values@x_db a,
  emp b
WHERE b.empid               = 'SAME_UNIQUE_VAL'
AND (asset_id, asset_type) IN ((b.asset_x_id, 'X'), (b.asset_y_id, 'Y'));
```